# Unit of Work and Repository is needed with EF 4 and upper?

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, repository, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am thinking after several days... is really necessary to use UoW and Repository patterns with Entity Framework 5 and upper? I mean, the way of use and objectives of Repository Pattern are already achieve with EF (except for those you have several data sources)... and Unit of Work is used to set individual operations... that with EF internally is achieve too... So I just want to ask if at the point of view of Architecture software design is an over engineering implement those patters or not!

I know it sounds pretty silly, but I just want to make things simplest and professionally.

Thank you!!!

Comment: you should try it yourself and see how it feels.

Comment: Im on it, the only problem that I can see is if I have several data sources... I mean with a single EF you only have access to a single data source and using Repository Pattern you can have several data sources.

Comment: After several reading, well... With DbContext we have the UnitOfWork already implemented, and with DbSet we have the Repository Pattern... the only and very important principle to use is the Persistance Ignorance... Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a more practical decision rather than "rule".

Unit of Work / Repository pattern is design pattern. It is built to decouple business logic from data access layer in a way that there is a middle layer that exposes operations that are understandable to business logic so that business logic does not care how is data persisted.

This is good in situations where you might i.e. decide that Entity Framework is not good approach and you want to replace it with NHibernate. You wouldn't have to write all your business logic all over again, but rather just implement new Unit of Work / Repositories based on NHibernate and keep your business logic as it is.

Another good reason why to use this pattern is if ability to do unit tests.

There is probably few more good reasons, but in the end it comes down to practical decisions:

- Will I change my data access layer?
- Will there be time to do unit testing?
- How much time/budget do I have to finish off the project?

For a single developer / smaller projects / predefined frameworks - it is just unnecessary layer of abstraction.

You are 100% right that DbContext = UnitOfWork and DbSet = Repository, but they are merely just implementations and design pattern requires for your business logic to work with IUnitOfWork and I(class)Repository interfaces, rather than with with actual implementations (again decoupling).

Comment: Barisa, thank you a lot! On my experience I have not found a project that has changed it OR/M framework but from the other side but they use migrate from an active record pattern or table mapper pattern to Repository Pattern with some OR/M. Regarding the Unit Testing... what I use to do is to have my model in other layer, in case I need to make changes to my OR/M (generally updates).

Comment: With design patterns, nothing is black/white (binary). Good developers need to decide what pattern should be best used for particular scenario. Keep an open mind :)

Comment: Thats right Barisa! In fact in architecture meetings one thing that is not allowed is to say "that's wrong". I try to re-ask principles before I start a design and I was really concern about this. I dont like to do things complicated but I like to make those igonrance between layers and keep in mind that a company with years is going to be working with another's company system (because of sell, fusion, or what ever)

Answer (score 1):

If your architectural and design goals require your data access layer to be persistence ignorant, such as in DDD or maybe n-tier, then it may be necessary; otherwise Entity Framework's DbContext and DbSet's are already your unit of work and repository patterns. Most of the time it is not needed to abstract a redundant unit of work and repository pattern with EF.

It completely depends on your requirements and design goals, but even if you want to do this with unit testing in mind (TDD), it still isn't that useful. Integration tests are more useful with EF, and in that scenario the redundant unit of work/repository pattern is unnecessary.

Comment: David, the only thing that I think is right after a lot of theorical reading was the Persistance Ignorance principle and the fact that all companies in a moment or another are going to coexists with another company systems (because of sell or something like that). Another book to keep in mind apart of the Domain Driven Design of Eric Evans, is the "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" of Martin Fowler. There are others, but these are just the basis. THANKS FOR YOUR TIME MAN!!!